# Dynamically rendering controls and binding to them in knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a JSON payload delivered by an ajax call to my knockout viewmodel. The structure of the payload is similar to:

```
{  
   "categories":[  
      {  
         "name":"Category 1",
         "questions":[  
            {  
               "id": 1,
               "questionText":"Question?",
               "controlType":"text"
            },
            {  
               "id": 2,
               "questionText":"Question?",
               "controlType":"radiobutton",
               "possibleAnswers":[  
                  {  
                     "answerId":1,
                     "text":"Yes"
                  },
                  {  
                     "answerId":2,
                     "text":"No"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Inside of my template I have a ForEach loop that iterates over all of the categories, and then a second ForEach loop that iterates over all of the questions for that category. I'm needing to dynamically create inputs, selects, and textareas based on the "controlType" of each question, and then bind these to an observableArray with a structure similar to:

```
[  
   {  
      "questionId":1,
      "answerId":1
   }
]
```

I made a function that can dynamically render the html within the foreach, but I'm not sure how to do the rest.

Here's a demo template:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:categories">
    <h2 data-bind="text:name"></h2>
    <div data-bind="foreach:questions">
        <span data-bind="text:questionText"></span>
        <div data-bind="html:$parents[0].createControl($data)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I bind and store the results from these inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using [templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) along with [if binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) would be wise here.

```
<div data-bind="foreach:categories">
    <h2 data-bind="text:name"></h2>
    <div data-bind="foreach:questions">
        <span data-bind="text:questionText"></span>
        <!-- ko if: controlType() == "radiobutton" -->
            <div data-bind="template: { name: 'radio-template', data: $data }"></div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: controlType() == "other-type" -->
            <div data-bind="template: { name: 'other-type-template', data: $data }"></div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

You could define templates like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="radio-template">
    <h3 data-bind="text: questionText"></h3>
    <div data-bind="foreach:possibleAnswers">
        <!-- you html here -->
    </div>
</script>
```

As for storing the answers, why not add a `selectedAnswer` to the questions?

```
{  
   "categories":[  
      {  
         "name":"Category 1",
         "questions":[  
            {  
               "id": 1,
               "questionText":"Question?",
               "controlType":"text"
            },
            {  
               "id": 2,
               "questionText":"Question?",
               "controlType":"radiobutton",
               "possibleAnswers":[  
                  {  
                     "answerId":1,
                     "text":"Yes"
                  },
                  {  
                     "answerId":2,
                     "text":"No"
                  }
               ],
               "selectedAnswer": -1
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Another solution is to have an array of answers and question ids:

```
{  
   "categories":[  
      {  
         "answers": [ "questionId": 1, "answer": { "id": -1, "value": "" } ]
         "name":"Category 1",
         "questions":[  
            {  
               "id": 1,
               "questionText":"Question?",
               "controlType":"text"
            },
            {  
               "id": 2,
               "questionText":"Question?",
               "controlType":"radiobutton",
               "possibleAnswers":[  
                  {  
                     "answerId":1,
                     "text":"Yes"
                  },
                  {  
                     "answerId":2,
                     "text":"No"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```